# How to add text from JSON inside "<p>"?

Tags: html, reactjs, contentful

I'm using Contentful to get a description text and the description has "blocks" of text, but when I add it to my code, the output looks as if it was a single line of text.

I'm using React and passing the description as a prop, so I'm only able to edit the whole text. Is there anyway I can edit it? Or do I have to import the block separated from Contentful?

Component passing the text:

```
<Section
  bgImg={images.section1}
  title={data.section1Title}
  description={data.section1Description}
/>
```

Component receiving the text:

```
<div className="description">{description}</div>
```

Here's what I mean: https://codepen.io/ViniciusBortoletto/pen/jOOBdGy

Comment: can you add your exact code?

Comment: The title of your question does not really match the question itself. I don't see any `<p>`? And how does your codepan link relate to the react component and the `div`?  And where is the JSON and what problem do you have with it?

Comment: You'll need to add the string as it is returned from the JSON for us to be able to offer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options. The first would be what you mentioned and separate them via Contenful.

Or alternatively you could do something on the React side and use Innerhtml and pass the description with the < p > tags inside of it.

```
{
 "desc": "<p>First block: Lorem ipsum</p><p>Second block: lorem ipsum</p>"
}
```

If you go the InnerHTML route, do be aware of the possible security issues. Here's a React package I found that might help:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inner-html